# Encrypting data with PHP and MYSQL (SHA1, MD5, MCRYPT_RIHNDAEL_256)

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, hash, sha1

I'm a little confused with the best practices of encoding data, I'm dealing with very sensitive data so need to do/learn the best method to protect the data:

1. I'm currenting hashing all Passwords with a combination of SHA1, MD5 and hashBCRYPT all of which use salt with a large mixed character keys.
2. All personal data I'm currently encrypting with PHP MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256

Is it worth me also adding AES_ENCRYPT so the the data is also encrypted with MYSQL? I have a read a few things saying PHP is the better method when you need to search and fetch data regularly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: SHA1, MD5 both of which shouldn't be used for passwords. Read why here http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure - Use something more of "this century".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be rolling your own hashing for passwords. Use PHP's built in `password_hash()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

As for encrypting user information, you probably don't want to be rolling your own library either, there are many existing PHP libraries for encrypting that will save you from making mistakes, such as Defuse, PHPSecLib, PHPCrypt, etc.

Comment: What's the downside to using multiple hashing methods?

Comment: You will get no benefit from doing this. MD5 is not adequate for password hashing. PHP's `password_hash()` is very specifically designed to do password hashing, and it will be automatically upgraded in the future, saving you from problems down the road.

Comment: Please do not try to invent new security schemes. The chances are huge that you will end up with something that's not secure at all or at least not as secure as you' expect. Encryption is a delicate art and we should rely on trusted libraries which have been scutinized by some experts.

Comment: I believe as Fred is using a combination of multiple hashing methods with salt, it makes so much tougher to break it.

Comment: Thank you for this good information!

For encrypting data,I'm just taking a look at:
http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/crypt/examples.html
Is there a library that you would recommend?

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim it is a mistake to think this way. Merely throwing more hash mehtods at it, that aren't designed for password hashing (but instead, like with MD5, are designed for high speed hashing, and have many security flaws) does not enhance security. PHP's `password_hash()` already does what is needed. It will run proper hash methods hundreds/thousands of times for you, automatically.

Comment: @FredPerryMunnelly "Is there a library that you would recommend?" https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/11/choosing-right-cryptography-library-for-your-php-project-guide